# Suffix in toponyms / inconsistency

Tags: suffix, place-name

In German, the suffix `-er` is often used to show affiliation of a product or resident with a certain city or place.

E.g

> Berliner Weisse
>   Stuttgarter Zoo

However, sometimes this is inconsistent. There is, for example, the German city of Saarbrücken, whose local newspaper is called "Saarbrücker Zeitung". The same is true for the federal state of Thüringen and the "Thüringer Wald"

In a linguistic way, how can one explain why in these cases, the names are the way they are, instead of

> Saarbrück**en**er Zeitung

or

> Thüring**en**er Wald

Comment: Did you note this mainly happens on place names ending with *-er* and *-en*? Also try speaking out loud your "well-formed" examples without twisting your tounge.

Comment: Thanks, @tofro I think it's obvious that it would sound (and read) weird if these were build in the standard way. My question, though, is, if there is a linguistic rule to explain this. This is because someone argued with me that "Saarbrücker Zeitung" is, in fact, wrong.

Comment: Dies hier ist ein DEUTSCH-Forum. Wenn deine Muttersprache Deutsch ist (wovon ich aufgrund deines Profils ausgehe), dann wäre es günstig, wenn du deine Fragen hier auch auf Deutsch stellen würdest. Die meisten Menschen, die hier Fragen beantworten, sprechen nämlich ebenfalls Deutsch als Muttersprache. Als Regel gilt aber, dass man Antworten in derselben Sprache schreiben sollte, in der die Frage gestellt wurde. Wenn du nun auf Englisch fragst, entsteht die Situation, dass sich deutsche Muttersprachler in einer Fremdsprache über die deutsche Sprache unterhalten. Das sollte man besser vermeiden.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Warum sollte das vermieden werden? Wer hier tätig ist, ist offensichtlich der Englischen Sprache mächtig. Abgesehen davon ist das StackExchange Network englischsprachig, was der Grund dafür ist, dass ich Fragen auf Englisch formuliere. Ganz abgesehen davon sollte das aber vielleicht von hier nach Meta verlagert werden. Prinzipiell wäre ich an einer konstruktiven Diskussion hierzu schon interessiert :)

Comment: @Sprottenwels: Nimm mich als Beispiel: ich bin zwar der englischen Sprache mächtig, aber nur auf Level B2 oder C1. Meine Muttersprache Deutsch hingegen beherrsche ich auf dem Level C2. Daher mache ich deutlich mehr Fehler, wenn ich Antworten auf Englisch schreibe, als auf Deutsch. In Meta wurde das auch schon mehrfach diskutiert, zuletzt hier: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/1221/1487

Comment: @Sprottenwels: Siehe auch: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/830/1487

Comment: Well, I for example would love to see the interesting questions and answer in English, since my German is not at so good level.

Comment: @tofro: Interestingly, *Saarbrückener* sounds pretty "normal" and pronouncable to me, as opposed to *Thüringener*. Might be related to the different syllable stress patterns.

Comment: Dazu hat auch mal der [Zwiebelfisch](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-wie-heisst-der-buergermeister-von-wesel-a-297117.html) was geschrieben.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Im Wahrig stehen dazu folgende Regeln:

> **Einwohnerbezeichnungen auf -er zu Ortsnamen auf -en**
>
> Bei der Bildung von Einwohnerbezeichnungen auf *-er* zu Ortsnamen auf *-en* bleibt die Endung *-en* des Ortsnamens in der Regel dann erhalten, wenn der Ortsname zweisilbig ist ...(Aachener, Dresd(e)ner, Essener, Gießener, Hagener, Münch(e)ner, Siegener, Singener. Ausnahmen: Barmer, Binger, Bremer, Emder (auch Emdener), Lüner, Uelzer)
>
> ...Dagegen wird bei Ortsnamen auf *-en*, die mehr als zwei Silben aufweisen, das *-en* im Ortsnamen im Allgemeinen getilgt:
>   (Donaueschingen, Eisleben (Eisleber), Erlangen, Göttingen, **Saarbrücken**, ... Ausnahme: Leverkusen)
>
> Bei Ortsnamen auf *-hausen, -kirchen* und *-hagen* kommen Bildungen mit und ohne Tilgung von *-en* vor.

Ob Wegfall oder nicht hängt also in erster Linie von der Anzahl der Silben des Ortes ab. Nach diesen Regeln also tatsächlich eindeutig **Saarbrücker** und **Thüringer**.

Für *Regeln* haben diese *Regeln* für meine Begriffe allerdings ziemlich viele Ausnahmen...

Answer (score 3):

Da du aus Saarbrücken kommst, und auch einen deutschen Nickname verwendest, antworte ich hier auf Deutsch.

---

Wenn ein Ortsname auf -en endet, und man davon eine Ableitung macht, die auf -er enden soll, dann kommt nur selten etwas heraus, das leicht und geschmeidig aus dem Mund flutscht. Im Fall der »*Saarbrückener Zeitung*« ginge das ja noch, aber bei »*Thüringener Wald*« muss die Zunge schon recht flink im Mund herum huschen, und das sauber zu artikulieren.

Daher haben sich ein paar Menschen angewöhnt, eine Silbe wegzulassen. Diese Verkürzung scheint allgemein angenommen worden zu sein, und ist mittlerweile längst Bestandteil des Standarddeutschen Wortschatzes:

> Saarbrücken -> Saarbrück**er** Zeitung
>   Thüringen -> Thüring**er** Wald
>   Solingen -> Soling**er** Stahlwaren
>   Bremen -> Brem**er** Stadtmusikanten

Manchmal verschwindet aber auch nur das E vor dem N, was aber trotzdem zum Verschwinden einer Silbe führt:

> München -> Münch**ner** Freiheit
>   Neunkirchen -> Neunkirch**ner** Straße
>   Dresden -> Dresd**ner** Straße
>   Baden -> Bad**ner** Bahn

Aber es gibt auch Beispiele, wo das nicht gemacht wird:

> Essen -> Ess**ener** Brot
>   Baden -> Bad**ener** Hof

Wie die Beispiele [Badner Bahn](http://www.wlb.at/eportal3/ep/channelView.do/pageTypeId/71526/channelId/-49911) und [Badener Hof](https://www.badenerhof.at/de/) zeigen, die beide von derselben Stadt (Baden, 15 km südlich von Wien) abgeleitet sind, gibt es auch keine wirklich konsistente Regel dafür, wann welche Verkürzung angebracht ist. Deine völlig richtige Beobachtung, dass hier eine Unregelmäßigkeit vorliegt, gilt also sogar dann, wenn man sich nur die Ortsnamen ansieht, die mit *-en* enden.

Comment: Danke. Ich schließe hieraus, dass es in der Tat keine Möglichkeit gibt, anderweitig zu argumentieren und es im Prinzip eine Streitfrage bleiben muss, ob nun die eine oder andere Variante korrekt ist?

Comment: @Sprottenwels Linguistik ist ohnehin eine Streitfrage. Aber die entsprechenden Orte benutzen schon eine Form, die als korrekt anzusehen ist. Verkürzung/Verschlucken redundanter Silben ist auch kein seltenes Phänomen, so dass dein Freund sich mit der Behauptung, *Saarbrücker* sei falsch, schon weit aus dem Fenster lehnt.

Comment: Der Duden behauptet in [Band 9](https://books.google.de/books?id=1-HBDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA270&ots=rtA5tdnry9&dq=%22aacher%22%20%22binger%22%20duden&hl=de&pg=PA270#v=onepage&q=%22aacher%22%20%22binger%22%20duden&f=false), die Formen ohne "-en" seien tatsächlich
die älteren (z.B. früher "Aacher", im Dialekt heute noch "Öcher");
erst später sei man dazu übergegangen, auch bei Ortsnamen auf "-en"
die Endung "-er" an den vollständigen Ortsnamen anzuhängen.